# How do I generate both client and interface code from WSDL.exe?

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I'm writing some .NET 2.0 ASMX services. I have a scenario where I need to generate a web service proxy with WSDL.exe, but the generated class doesn't implement an interface, so I can't fake out the web service for testing.

Here's one approach I'm trying, but it doesn't compile at the moment: I'm aware that WSDL.exe can generate interfaces using the `/serverInterface` option. In principle, I'd like to generate **both** Interface and Proxy classes as follows:

> wsdl MyWebService.wsdl /nologo /l:CS
>   /namespace:Juliet.Services
>   /o:C:\projects\JulietService\MyWebServiceInterface.cs
>   /serverInterface
>
> wsdl MyWebService.wsdl /nologo /l:CS
>   /namespace:Juliet.Services
>   /o:C:\projects\JulietService\MyWebServiceProxy.cs

Then include both files in my project. Afterward I should be able to derive my own class from the generated Proxy and implement the generated interface as follows:

```
public class MockableWebService : MyWebService, IMyWebServiceSoap11Binding
{
    // No implementation, the interface is already implicitly implemented
    // from the methods in the base class.
}
```

This should work in principle, **except** both interface and proxy files will auto-generate the same class definitions for my Request/Response messages, resulting in hundreds of errors of the type `The namespace 'Juliet.Services' already contains a definition for 'ABC'`.

---

I'd like to keep the interface/proxy generation as automated as possible -- meaning, I want to avoid modifying generated code by hand at all costs.

Can anyone suggest a way to generate the interface and proxy at the same time with WSDL.exe, or a better way to get the results described above?

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't the .NET 2.0 WSDL.EXE generate partial classes? Then you can implement the interface on another class part:

```
public partial class MockableWebService : IMyWebServiceSoap11Binding
{
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion easier for me to avoid deriving my own class from the generated proxy, but I have a little different problem: WSDL.exe generates proxy and interfaces classes as separate operations. The generated proxy and generated interface contain definitions will also include definitions for Request/Response messages -- end result, I can't include the files for both outputs because they contain duplicate class definitions. I don't want to generate the responses in different namespaces, ideally I'd like to suppress generation of Request/Response messages for one of my files.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not possible. It's also not what you asked for.

Comment: +1, would also be interested why someone downvoted this... also: @Juliet, you should accept this as an answer.